# How to recursively find RAR and Rxx files and copy them with zsh

Tags: file-management, file-transfer, zsh

I have my downloaded directory with many `rar` files and I'm trying to move them. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a `zsh` solution, here you are:

```
mv (#i)**/*.r(ar|<->) destination
```

`(#i)`makes the search case-insensitive

`**` is searching recursively, use `***` if the search should follow symbolic links

`<->` matches a number, but you can also specify a  range, e.g. <1-20>

`(A|B)` matches `A` or `B`

So, with the above command you will capture *.rar, *.r01, ..., but also *.RAR, *.R1, *.R2

Answer (score 1):

you can do some thing like:

```
find -name ".rar" -exec cp {} dest_dir \;
```